# Delay Loaded Package with custom search path

Tags: package, c++builder, bpl

I wrote a **BPL** project and added output **.bpi** file to another **EXE** project. The **EXE** project compiles and links well. The **EXE** runs well if I put **.bpl** file in the same folder as **.exe** file. However, the **EXE** fails to run if I put **.bpl** file in other folders than **.exe** file, and it shows "The program can't start because XXX.bpl is missing...".

I also wrote a **DLL** version and put **.dll** file in other folders than **.exe** file. I added the **.dll** to the **EXE** project's "C++ Linker"->"Advanced"->"Delay load DLLs" list, and added `SetDllDirectory()` function call to my custom search path. The **EXE** runs well. It seems that **.bpl** can not work the same as **.dll** if delay-loaded with custom search path via `SetDllDirectory()`, am I right?

Test BPL code is like following:

"***TestPackage.h***"

```
class PACKAGE TestPackage
{
   TestPackage( void );
   int GetInt( void );
};
```

"***TestPackage.cpp***"

```
#include "TestPackage.h"
#pragma package(smart_init)

TestPackage::TestPackage( void ){}
int TestPackage::GetInt( void ){ return 1000; }
```

And the test form application code is like following:

"***TestApp.cpp***"

```
#include "TestPackage.h"

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click( TObject* Sender )
{
   TestPackage* package = new TestPackage;
   int ret = package->GetInt();
   Application->MessageBoxA( IntToStr(ret).c_str(), L"test", 0 );
}
```

I disabled both "**Build with runtime packages**" and "**Dynamic RTL**" in application options. I put ***TestPackage.bpl*** in the folder as **EXE** and the **EXE** worked well. I could upgraded **BPL** separately from **EXE**, say to let `TestPackage::GetInt()` return other numbers. So the net result seems I can deploy my custom **BPL** with **EXE**, and other **BPL**s, like **RTL** and **VCL**, are still statically linked in **EXE**. The only limitation is that my custom **BPL** must be in the same folder as **EXE**, is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: A BPL **is** a DLL, just with a different file extension.  A BPL is loaded into memory the same way a DLL is. The main difference is that a BPL has additional things that are loaded by `LoadPackage()` (which calls `LoadLibrary()` internally). I don't know if the linker can delay-load a BPL, though (I have never tried). You might need to use a [delay-load hook](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/SysInit.SetDliNotifyHook2) to handle the `dliNotePreLoadLibrary` event to call `LoadPackage()` instead of `LoadLibrary()`. Otherwise, forget delay-loading and just call `LoadPackage()` directly

Comment: Hi Remy. I found that BPL is implicitly added to EXE project's runtime packages list, and I unchecked "Build with runtime packages" option. Does it mean that the BPL MUST be found in EXE's library search path (PATH or same directory as EXE), otherwise EXE can not run due to BPL missing? In other words, even if I use `LoadPackage()`, the BPL search path is always the same, and I can not specify the full path of BPL to `LoadPackage()`.

Comment: if you build *without* runtime packages enabled, the package content will be statically compiled directly into the EXE, no BPL file needed. It is only when runtime packages are enabled that BPL files are linked to and need to be deployed.

Comment: Hi @Remy. I don't want to deploy other BPLs with EXE except my own BPL, such as vcl and rtl, as a result I unchecked "Build with runtime packages". The end users only have one EXE and one (my custom) BPL in different directories (ex. Bin\ and Libs\), and the BPL can be upgraded separately from the EXE. I thought I can achieve this as I do with DLL via delay-loading and `SetDllDirectory()`.

Comment: you can't deploy your own BPL and not also deploy the RTL BPLs as well. They go together. By their nature, a BPL links to other BPLs, they are not static. So either you build with runtime packages enabled and deploy a smaller EXE and relevant BPLs, or you build with runtime packages disabled and deploy a larger EXE and no BPLs.

Comment: Hi @Remy. I edited my question. It seems that I could deploy my custom BPL and EXE, while VCL and RTL are still statically linked in EXE. Do I misunderstand anything?